# How to add a column to my Scala dataframe without creating a new dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

This is the code I have so far to take the row-wise average of selected columns.

```scala
val df2 = df1.select(num_columns.map(col).reduce((c1,c2) => c1 + c2) as "sum")
  .select("sum")
  .withColumn("avg",(col("sum")/num_cols.length))
```

However, I would like to just add the "avg" column to df1, instead of creating df2. But whenever I try this same code using withColumn, it doesn't work.

What would be the syntax to simply create the same "avg" column in df1?

Comment: Do you mean that you have correct desired result in df2 with this statement?

Comment: Yeah I just want it to be a new column at the end of df1 instead of creating an entire new dataframe

Comment: if you do `df1=df1.select(num_columns.map(col).reduce((c1,c2)=>c1+c2) as "sum").select("sum").withColumn("avg",(col("sum")/num_cols.length))
`
You wont be creating new dataframe, you will in essence be overwriting it, adding new column

Comment: No but I want the new column to be added to the end of the old dataframe, including all the original columns from df1